# Modal view at right half of ipad's screen?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I need to modify a view's modal presentation with this parameters:

1 - Modal view only fills the ipad's right half of the screen.
2 - The animation runs from the left half of the screen.

I have search in iosframeworks.com, cocoacontrols.com, the books from big nerd rach, ios recipes, ios pushing the limits, stackoverflow and google. Is some posibility to do that?
Thanks for your assistance

For testing, after two days of searching answers, I create the following code, I'm executing the following code since the root view controller CMMainView, the viewcontroller CMVistaModal is empty, its doesn't have any overrided method nor xib nor another variable, the device family is iPad

```
-(IBAction)accion:(id)sender
{

CMVistaModal *modal = [[CMVistaModal alloc] init];

[modal setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

[self presentViewController:modal animated:NO completion:nil];
[modal.view.superview setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
[modal.view.superview setFrame:CGRectMake(800, 120, 200, 500)];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    modal.view.superview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-200, 0);
}];
}
```

how can i perform the same operation but overriding the methods from CMVistaModal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Just make a new view and add it to your existing view and animate it into position. You can have another view appear behind it blocking any touches to other views.

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible. It just depends on how much work you wish to put in.

So a standard `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` or `UIModalPresentationPageSheet` comes for free. But what you want isn't standard so you have to bake your own.

What I would do here is create a "fake" modal.

With

```
XYViewController -> Container View

Container View -> Semi Opaque blocker
               -> Half Screen Content
```

The blocker covers the entire screen and goes in immediately and prevents interaction with the rest of the UI

Then animate the "Half Screen Content" in from the left with a standard frame animate. How you choose to dismiss this fake modal is up to you but if it comes in from left perhaps it should depart to the left.

Comment: How I present it? With the message [self presentViewController:modal animated:NO completion:nil]; ?

Comment: No with a bunch of presentation code that you write for yourself. This isn't standard so it isn't free.